# Interpreat python syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
question_num = 5, num_1 = 7, num_2 = 9
statement =  '#%s: %s x %s =  ' % (question_num, num_1, num_2)
```

What is the meaning of the statement syntax? Please explain how does this syntax work?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting

Comment: That's not valid Python. Maybe if you use semicolons in the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `%s` acts as a placeholder of your data (variable). There are even better ways to do same like using f-string or `format` method.

```
statement = f"#{q}: {n} x {n2} = "
```